# Are you required to read any of Langdon books by Dan Brown to properly understand and enjoy the next ones?

Tags: reading-order, dan-brown

Technically speaking, Dan Brown's Langdon books are part of a series in a common universe.

But at first glance, they don't seem to be all that related to each other - more like Fleming's 007 than Harry Potter.

Are you required to read any of Langdon books by Dan Brown to properly understand and enjoy the next ones?

If not, is there important information in any of the earlier books that the reader of later books would find necessary to increase their understanding/enjoyment (assuming they aren't afraid of spoilers)

Comment: Related question (albeit about their adaptation to a different medium): [Watching order for the Dan Brown films?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62550/49)

Answer (score 6):

I read the books out of order (first *The Da Vinci Code*, then *The Lost Symbol*, then *Angels and Demons*, and then *Inferno*), and I don't think there is much reason to read them in any particular order. The stories are completely separate from each other; the only connection between them (besides Langdon himself) that I recall is a [brief mention of Vittoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Langdon#Angels_.26_Demons) in *The Da Vinci Code*.

Comment: After clicking through to the Movies question linked to in a comment below the question, I found that my answer matches [the accepted answer there](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/62552)